# How do I read only a part of a string?

Tags: c++

Question may seem like a duplicate but I have researched and found nothing that would actually answer my question.

So I have a task that let's the user input groceries as a string, the weight and price as doubles. Simple enough, right? Well, the problem is that the user will enter it in the following format:

```
Enter product 1: Potato; 5 kg; 49 kr;
Enter product 2: Carrot; 0.5 kg; 13 kr;
Enter product 3: Onion; 0.1 kg; 2 kr;
```

And then the products will be sorted in a specific manner. However that is not what I need help with, I have a problem with reading in only "Potato", "5" and "49" and store them in seperate variables.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct Product_Type
{
    string name;
    double weight;
    double price;
};

void get (Product_Type & p)
{
    cin >> p.name;
    cin.ignore(1);
    cin >> p.weight;
    cin.ignore(2);
    cin >> p.price;
    cin.ignore(2);
    
}
```

If I do it like this, I will store "Potato;" and not "Potato" in my name variable. So my question is how do I manipulate a string to only read to a certain index and store the content in a variable? I don't want to read the actual `semi-colons`. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: You may want to read up about what [`ignore()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) actually does. What makes you think,  that `';'` is a delimiter actually?

Comment: I don't think that ';' is a delimiter in general cases but in this specific case, I believe it is. I only want to store "Potato" in my name variable and not "Potato;". I only want to store "Carrot" in my name variable and not "Carrot;". Thus, ';' should, in my eyes, be regarded as a string delimiter.

Comment: Well, in that case it seems you should first read the whole line, then split using `;` (`std::istringstream` and `std::getline()` come handy for this), and trim whitespaces off.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how formatted input and unformatted input works.

Please read [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream) about it.

You do not need `ignore` at all. You can do all with simple statements.

But the precondition is that the input matches your specification. Any input of wrong data leads to a problem. So, let's assume that the input follows the above pattern. OK.

---

Regarding your problem, where you read "potato;" instead of "potato". This is because you use a formatted input function `>>` to read a string. And this function will stop, if it sees a white space and not before. It will also ignore leading white space by default, but that is not important here.

To solve the problem to read a string until a certain delimiter, you can use the unformatted input function `std::getline`. Please see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

So, to get the name, you may write `std::getline(std::cin, p.name, ';');`. This will read the name from the input stream, including the semicolon, but store the pure name, without the semicolon in the string.

Next we are talking about reading `5 kg; 49 kr`. We want to have the "weight". We can simply use formatted input function `>>` to get it. There is a white space after that, so, very simple. You can write `std::cin >> p.weight;` to get it.

Next we have to read `kg; 49 kr`. So, we will use a dummy string and with that can read the "kg;" which we do simple not use. So, with a dummy string "s1", we can write `std::cin >> s1;`. The `kg;` will be gone from the stream.

Now we see  `49 kr;`. Reading the price is again simple using `>>`. We will write `std::cin >> p.price;` and have it.

Last but not least we need to read the rest of the line, including the enter. For that we use again `std::getline`. No need to specify any delimiter, because the standard delimiter is already '\n'.

Then the full code looks like the below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Product_Type
{
    std::string name;
    double weight;
    double price;
};
void get(Product_Type& p)
{
    std::string s1, s2;
    std::getline(std::cin, p.name, ';');
    std::cin >> p.weight;
    std::cin >> s1;
    std::cin >> p.price;
    std::getline(std::cin, s2);

}
int main() {
    Product_Type pt;
    get(pt);
    std::cout << pt.name << " --> " << pt.weight << " --> " << pt.price << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

---

But this is not considered to be good. There may be errors in the input and with that the failbit of `std::cin` would be set and you cannot continue to read.

Therefore, normally, we would read first the complete line with `std::getline` which will most likely always work. Then, we "convert" the string to a stream using an `std::istringstream` to be able to extract the data from there. If the complete line has an error, then only the temporary `std::istringstream` will be gone. So this approach is a little bit more robust.

This could then look like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

struct Product_Type
{
    std::string name;
    double weight;
    double price;
};
void get(Product_Type& p)
{
    std::string line, s1, s2;
    std::getline(std::cin, line);

    std::istringstream iss(line);

    std::getline(iss, p.name, ';');
    iss >> p.weight;
    iss >> s1;
    iss >> p.price;
    std::getline(iss, s2);

    if (not iss)
        std::cerr << "\nError: Problem with input\n\n";
}
int main() {
    Product_Type pt;
    get(pt);
    std::cout << pt.name << " --> " << pt.weight << " --> " << pt.price << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

---

And a little bit more advanced with chaining the io-functions, we can write

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

struct Product_Type
{
    std::string name;
    double weight;
    double price;
};
void get(Product_Type& p)
{
    std::string line, s1, s2;
    std::getline(std::cin, line);

    std::istringstream iss(line);

    std::getline(std::getline(iss, p.name, ';') >> p.weight >> s1 >> p.price, s2);
    if (not iss)
        std::cerr << "\nError: Problem with input\n\n";
}
int main() {
    Product_Type pt;
    get(pt);
    std::cout << pt.name << " --> " << pt.weight << " --> " << pt.price << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

---

All the above is very simplified, but may give you a starting point for better ideas.

Comment: Thank you, I got a follow up question tho. What if someone inputs something like:

`"          Carrot;  52 kg; 13 kr"` How would I remove the spaces in my getline? I tried doing it like this:


   ´ string s1, s2;
    getline(cin, p.name, ';'); 
    
    for (size_t i {}; i < p.name.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (isspace(p.name.at(i)))
        {
            p.name.erase(i,1);
        }
    }
    
    cin >> p.weight; 
    cin >> s1;
    cin >> p.price; 
    getline(cin, s2); ´

But it doesnt remove the spaces

Comment: `std::ws` will be your friend. Please read: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/ws and write:  ` std::getline(std::cin>>std::ws, p.name, ';');`This will eat the leading white spaces.